# How do i send parameter in ajax function call in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating an online exam application in PHP and am having trouble with the AJAX calls.

I want the questions to be fetched (and used to populate a div) using an AJAX call when one of the buttons on the right are clicked. These buttons are not static; they are generated on the server (using PHP).

[image: Here is interface of front end]

I'm looking for an AJAX call to be something like this:

```
functionname=myfunction(some_id){
ajax code
success: 
html to question output div
}
```

and the button should call a function like this:

```
<button class="abc" onclick="myfunction(<?php echo $question->q_id ?>)">
```

Please suggest an AJAX call that would make this work

Comment: i tried to find such code, i know how it should be done but, i don't know exact jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button class="abc" questionId="<?php echo $question->q_id ?>">
```

**Script**

```
$('.abc').click(function () {
 var qID = $(this).attr('questionId');
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "questions.php", //Your required php page
     data: "id=" + qID, //pass your required data here
     success: function (response) { //You obtain the response that you echo from your controller
         $('#Listbox').html(response); //The response is being printed inside the Listbox div that should have in your html page. Here you will have the content of $questions variable available
     },
     error: function () {
         alert("Failed to get the members");
     }
 });
```

})

The **type** variable tells the browser the type of call you want to make to your PHP document. You can choose GET or POST here just as if you were working with a form.

**data** is the information that will get passed onto your form.

**success** is what jQuery will do if the call to the PHP file is successful.

More on ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

**PHP**

```
 $id = gethostbyname($_POST['id']);
 //$questions= query to get the data from the database based on id
return $questions;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way. jQuery has in-built operators for stuff like this.

Firstly, when you generate the buttons, I'd suggest you create them like this:

```
<button id="abc" data-question-id="<?php echo $question->q_id; ?>">
```

Now create a listener/bind on the button:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'button#abc', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var q_id = jQuery(this).data('question-id'); // the id

    // run the ajax here.
});
```

Comment: the almighty $ > jQuery

Comment: @CoryDanielson Would go with that, just habit at the moment! Stuck using jQuery instead of $ :(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have something like this to generate the buttons:

```
<button class="question" data-qid="<?php echo $question->q_id ?>">
```

And your event listener would be something like the following:

```
$( "button.question" ).click(function(e) {
  var button = $(e.target);
  var questionID = button.data('qid');
  var url = "http://somewhere.com";
  $.ajax({ method: "GET", url: url, success: function(data) {
    $("div#question-container").html(data);
  });
});
```